# XSLT lookup table: replace element with element from the lookup

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to use lookup tables in XSLT. I have the following xmls:

data.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<labels>
 <label>
  <name>Thomas Eliot</name>
  <address>
   <city>Hartford</city>
   <state id= "CT"/>
  </address>
 </label>
 <label>
  <name>Ezra Pound</name>
  <address>
   <city>Hailey</city>
    <state>
     <name>New York</name>
   </state>
  </address>
 </label>
</labels>
```

lookup.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<states>
 <state id="CT">
   <name>Connecticut</name>
 </state>
</states>
```

For the output I want:

```
<labels>
 <label>
  <name>Thomas Eliot</name>
  <address>
   <city>Hartford</city>
   <state>
     <name>Connecticut</name>
   </state>
  </address>
 </label>
 <label>
  <name>Ezra Pound</name>
  <address>
   <city>Hailey</city>
   <state>
     <name>New York</name>
   </state>
  </address>
 </label>
</labels>
```

So I want to resolve the state id in the data.xml and copy the content of the corresponding element from lookup.xml

I'm stuck with the following xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:key name="lookupKey" match="state" use="@id"/>

    <xsl:variable name="lookupStore" select="document('lookup.xml')/states/"/>
    <xsl:template match="state[@id]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$lookupStore">
            <xsl:with-param name="current" select="."/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="states">
        <xsl:param name="current"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('lookupKey', $current/address/state/@id)/."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Why `<xsl:template match="state[@id]">` does not apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the differences:

```
<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name="lookupStore" select="document('lookup.xml')/states"/>

<xsl:key name="lookupKey" match="state" use="@id"/>

<xsl:template match="state[@id]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$lookupStore">
            <xsl:with-param name="current" select="."/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="states">
    <xsl:param name="current"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="key('lookupKey', $current/@id)/name"/>
</xsl:template>
```

---

If you like, you could shorten the whole thing to:

```
<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name="lookupdoc" select="document('lookup.xml')"/>

<xsl:key name="state-by-id" match="state" use="@id"/>

<xsl:template match="state/@id">
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="."/>
    <!-- switch context to the lookup document -->
    <xsl:for-each select="$lookupdoc">
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('state-by-id', $id)/name"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```